# Charging 6 NiMH batteries in series via solar

Tags: battery-charging, embedded, solar-cell, nimh

I'm currently working on a project in which a Atmega328 is powered by 6AA NiMH batteries in series (7.5v, 2000MaH). It is in sleep mode most of the time, except to turn a servo a couple times a day, for a couple of seconds (Hence the need for the high voltage).

I have a solar panel at 12V and 1.8W, so maximum of 150mA. After doing a lot of research, and looking at this post: [Charging NiMH batteries with 1W solar panel, charge controller needed?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157069/charging-nimh-batteries-with-1w-solar-panel-charge-controller-needed) .
The maximum output for my solar panel is within the c/10 -> c/40 range that is safe for the NiMH batteries to be charged at.

My question is, none of the resources I could find explicitly say if what I am attempting is OK for multiple cells like I have.. Due to the remote nature of my device, charging each cell individually, or using a LiPo, is not an option.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:** Below is a PCB design for this circuit. According to @BruceAbbott The voltage of the panel would be fine, but since my servo can only handle a max of 8v, would the batteries still be able to lower to voltage to not damage my servo?[image]

I believe the reason it is safe is due to how the current and voltage is controlled from a solar panel, for example, this IV curve (NOT the panel i'm using, just an example.)[image]

This should ensure that the voltage never exceeds the dangerous limit?

Comment: You still need to limit the voltage.

Comment: What would that voltage be? Since my voltage and current source won't be guaranteed to be constant or known @winny. I was thinking of using a lm317 to limit current, since voltage doesn't seem to be hugely important from what I've read, but since the max current is low enough I was thinking I didn't need it

Comment: You need just need to limit the voltage (to about 8.6 volts) and prevent the batteries from discharging through the panel. It could be done with a zener diode, a rectifier diode, and a resistor.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK. So I'll just use a low drop off regulator for that I suppose. Was hoping to avoid that, since now the panel will have to have even more sun to ensure the voltage is high enough.. How did you get the 8.6 volts number?

Comment: This will probably work OK, but for the benefit of others who may come along, continuous trickle charging of NiMH is not recommended. Since this is solar based, it will not be continuous (charging will stop in the evening), but it is still not the ideal way to charge NiMH. Battery life will be reduced due to this method of charging compared with other methods.

Comment: Trickle charging is not 'ideal' but in this case it's the only viable option because there isn't enough power for fast charging. The cost of a sophisticated charger probably isn't worth the _potential_ saving in battery life.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I agree 100% with you. But I felt it a good idea to insert the cautionary comment so that others who may read it later do not take this question and answer as a blanket endorsement of trickle-charging NiMH.

Comment: Is your servo rated for 7.4V?

Comment: @BruceAbbott it's a hitec 5645. I thought it was rated at 7.4v but the spec sheet says 6. I've ran it plenty with the 6 pack setup before. Or, I can just run it with the 5v from my voltage regulator

Comment: That servo is only rated for 6V (ie. 5 cells, ~7.2V max). You should power it through a separate regulator. Use a regulator which has a shutdown pin if you want to turn the servo power off. Do not switch the ground lead! Idle current is only 3mA so you might not need to turn it off. Alternatively, run 5 cells and an LDO regulator for the MCU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The panel will automatically limit the current to a safe 'trickle' charge, so all you have to do is connect it directly to the battery.

If the panel has high dark current then a small Schottky diode in series will block the reverse current. Your panel probably has pretty low dark current so the diode may not be necessary, though it could be a good safety feature if the panel is wired remotely (a short in the panel leads won't short out the battery).

Comment: So is the voltage fine? Gotten mixed views and opinions on it

Comment: Yes, the voltage is fine. In fact the battery will never get 12V because the maximum voltage on trickle charge is about 1.45V per cell. The panel just has to be able to produce at least that much (+0.4V for the Schottky diode) at full current. 12V is higher than 9.1V so it's fine. The panel is running in current limiting mode so the 'extra' voltage is 'lost' inside the panel.

Comment: Note that the battery is the only thing that keeps the voltage below 9V. If your regulator can't handle 12V then you could put a 9.6V Zener diode across the panel to protect the regulator in case the battery becomes disconnected.

Comment: @BruceAbbott "12 V" solar panel  =~14 Vpp > 6xAA = 1.46*6=8.76 V. How can you say the voltage is fine?

Comment: @winny and Bruce please check my edit to my question. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If the batteries are fully charged, they won't clamp to ~8.7 V anymore and the voltage will just rise until they puke out their guts. Get yourself an MPPT/MPPC (tge new from Linear is fantastic) and buck, boost or buck/boost yourself to a suitable level. Theoretically you could run straight against the battery bank and program your voltage to 8.6 V, but better would be a charge controller from your intermediate rail. Or skip both and build yourself a linear pass regulator set to 8.6 V.

Comment: @winny "12V 1.8W" solar panel can only deliver 150mA at best (probably less than 100mA at peak sunlight in most installations) and any attempt to draw more will make the voltage drop. Basically the same as a 150mA trickle charger. The batteries _will_ limit the voltage and they _won't_ 'puke their guts out' with an average charge rate of  ~C/50.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that. They will need to burn almost the full 1.5 W as heat and the chemistry act as a zener. @Kyle Can you add a ~9 V zener anyway? It will only cost you a few cents and if I'm dead wrong, I'll PayPal you the money.

Comment: 1.5W for a few hours on a really bright day, spread over 6 cells - it's nothing to worry about. I recommended a 9V Zener in case the battery doesn't hold the voltage down (eg. if using AA cells in a holder where they might not make good contact). His circuit has other issues and the servo isn't even rated for 6 cells!

Comment: @BruceAbbott Would this not work? https://image.prntscr.com/image/ya769nOsQRyccQPHPu0fvw.png I've used the negative switching before without any issues. I even have this circuit on a protoboard and it works great.

Comment: Also @BruceAbbott I originally disconnected the hot side, but the servo would still say energized with the signal and ground. So I had no choice.

Comment: If you switch off the negative servo lead then it will float up to the positive, which in your case could be up to +8.7V. That means the servo is getting -8.7V on its signal input and the Arduino is getting +8.7V on its output. You will probably get away with it because the servo probably has a protection resistor on the signal input, but it's not good practice. Since the servo only draws 3mA on standby you could just stop sending servo pulses to shut it down - no power switching required!

Comment: "I originally disconnected the hot side, but the servo would still say energized with the signal and ground" - that makes no sense. How can it be 'energized' when it has no power? Your servo only draws 3mA on standby, 72mAh per day - not worth worrying about when you have a 2Ah battery that is recharged every day.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I need to disconnect it not for the power draw but so the servo is not held in place. With just the hot side disconnected the servo still holds position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60895/discussion-between-kyle-hunter-and-bruce-abbott).