# Can you charge a NIMH battery with a trickle charge NiCad battery charger

Tags: power-electronics

Purchased older RC airplane complete kit Air Tronics transmitter in kit not made anymore old NiCad battery (10 plus yes) was replaced with new 9.6v NIMH battery can the old NiCad trickle charger that plugs into the transmitter be used to charge the new NiMh battery that is now in the transmitter ? Thanks Vern

Comment: [Related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194953/nimh-or-li-ion-trickle-charge).

Answer (score 1):

The reccomended trickle charge current for most NiMH batteries is C/20  but for NiCd's it;s C/10

However NiMH typically has twice the capacitoy of similarly sized NiCd so the current comes out about right. So yes, you can use a NiCd trickle charger on NiMH cells.

Don't try to use a fast charger though, the NiMH voltage profile is different and the cells will be damaged.